# Access rights hierarchy

Tags: google-drive-api, slack

Drive-SDK Devs, thought you would be the best to ask.
Looking at Slack - Google drive integration for example, it is asking to give permission to following:

1. View the files on your Google Drive
   ...
2. View and manage google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app.

Questions is about the hierarchy of this capability based security levels:

Does this mean that Slack has **view** access to all google drive files and **manage** to those opened/created by Slack

or is (4) prevailing in which case (1) is superfluous?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are additive to the ACL. So Slack has full r/w rights to any files which are created/opened by it. Any files which have not been created/opened by Slack are able to be read by Slack, but may not be changed/deleted.

Comment: Thanks, do you maybe have a reference where this is documented?

Comment: try https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need

Comment: thanks, now maybe tangential a bit but why would Slack need read access to all my files (and not just those I've shared, imported into slack)?  I'm not trying to rant i wan't integration with Slack but I don't have to trust them in order to do so? Am I missing something?

Comment: Good question. I would have thought that readonly.metadata would be sufficient. Perhaps Slack tries to index your content. It's a question for the Slack guys.

Comment: I got response from Slack team:" Our app uses the read access to show the files in your GDrive account. Without this access, you wouldn't be able to use the upload option (in the [+] menu) for GDrive files." But as you said readonly.metadata should be sufficient.

Comment: And you were right! Latest from the Slack team: "I checked with my team on this and they indicated that the drive.readonly access is needed because we download and index the contents of the file so that it can be searched in Slack.

I hope that helps to better explain why we're using that scope. Let me know if you have further questions."

Comment: imho, not a great approach. As you say it concedes a lot of access for little benefit. I'd need to check, but I suspect that they could have delegated to Drive's built-in search without requiring content read access.